# what does it by raising a matrix to the power of $1/2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I came across the following which I did not understand at all.

Let $A$ be a positive semi-definite.
If $A(I-B)$ is positive definite, then the eigenvalues of $$A^{1/2}(I-B)A^{-1/2} = I -A^{1/2}BA^{-1/2}\tag 1$$ are all positive, which implies:
 $$\text {the eigenvalues of} \ B \ \text{are real and less than 1} \tag 2$$

(i) What are $A^{1/2}$ and $A^{-1/2}$ in (1)?

(ii) How does the positive definiteness of $A(I-B)$ imply the eigenvalues of (1) are all positive?

(iii) Also, why does (1) imply (2)?

I tried to figure these out by myself, I could not find a good reference to look up. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Given a matrix $A$ satisfying certain conditions, there exists a matrix say $M$ for now such that $M^2=A$. For instance if $A$ is diagonal with real non-negative coefficients, then such a $M$ is the diagonal matrix with coefficients the square root of the coefficients of $A$. In this case, we write $M=A^{1/2}$. One can do this in a more general context than just diagonal.

Comment: See the wikipedia article : 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix 
Look at the section on positive operator.

Answer (score 5):

### Answer to (1):

If $A$ is positive definite, then $A^{1/2}$ denotes the unique positive definite square root of $A$. That is, $A^{1/2}$ is the unique positive definite matrix $M$ satisfying $M^2 = A$.

Because $A^{1/2}$ is positive definite, it is invertible.  $A^{-1/2}$ denotes the inverse of $A^{1/2}$.

---

### Answer to (2):

If $A(I - B)$ is positive definite, then it has positive eigenvalues.  This implies that for any invertible matrix $S$, the congruent matrix $S^*[A(I-B)]S$ will also be positive definite.

Setting $S = A^{-1/2}$ (noting that $S = S^*$), we conclude that $A^{1/2}(I-B)A^{-1/2}$ must be positive definite, from which we may conclude that it has positive eigenvalues.

---

### Answer to (3):

We can write $A^{1/2}(I-B)A^{-1/2} = S^{-1}(I-B)S$, where $S$ is as above.  That is, $A^{1/2}(I-B)A^{-1/2}$ is **similar** to $I-B$.

Note, however, that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $B$ if and only if $1 - \lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $I-B$.

If both $I-B$ has positive eigenvalues, then for every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $B$, $1-\lambda$ is (real and) positive.  Thus, the eigenvalues of $B$ must be real less than $1$.

Comment: How do I know that $A^{1/2}$ exists? all I know is that $A(I-B)$ is positive definite, not that $A$ is positive definite

Comment: Are we given any information about $A$?  We must have at least been given that $A$ is invertible.  Given how $A$ is being used here, I highly suspect that $A$ is meant to be positive definite.

Comment: Any invertible matrix $A$ has at least *some* square root, but if $A$ is not positive semidefinite, the square root cannot be symmetric.

Comment: All I know is that A is positive semidefinite. If A is positive semidefinite, instead of positive definite, then is $A^{1/2}$ still well defined?

Comment: @user12345678910 if $A$ is non-invertible (that is, $A$ fails to be positive definite), then $A^{-1/2}$ is a meaningless expression, and at best we'd be able to conclude that the eigenvalues of $B$ are less than **or equal to** $1$.

Comment: If you've faithfully copied the line of reasoning presented, then either your reference has a typo (that is, shouldn't have said $A^{-1/2}$), or they forgot to mention that they were considering the case where $A$ is invertible (i.e. positive definite).

Comment: My bad. I missed that the author makes a little note: A is positive (semi)definite.

Comment: Is there a reason to consider the expanded expression $I -A^{1/2}BA^{-1/2}$  in my reasoning (2)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23290/discussion-between-omnomnomnom-and-user12345678910).

Comment: I just came back to this post, and in your answer (2), why is $S = S^{-1}$?

Comment: That last term is really 
$$
A^{-1/2}[A(I-B)]A^{-1/2}
$$
the $A$ there cancels.

Comment: I know that $A(I-B)$ is positive definite, but how/why does multiplying both sides by $A^{-1/2}$ preserve positive definiteness? The resulting product is not similar to $A(I-B)$

Comment: If $M$ is positive definite and $X$ is any invertible matrix, $XMX^*$ will be positive definite (and generally won't be similar). That's actually exactly what I wrote... the point then is not that $S = S^{-1}$, but that $S = S^*$.

Comment: What do you mean by $S^{\star}$?

Comment: The conjugate transpose (aka adjoint).

Comment: sorry for asking  a lot. So, why is then $S = S^{\star}$? Is this a property of a square root of a positive definite matrix?

Comment: Positive definite matrices are symmetric (Hermitian).  $A^{1/2}$ is usually defined to be the *positive definite* square root.

Comment: Is the matrix $A^2$ always a PSD for any matrix $A$?